# add special symbols in diff locales in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

i want to add more symbols of different locales using drop down menu list in CKEditor select special character color box.But , i am not able to find respective HTML code where i can add dropdown menu.
please guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your specialchar plugin's js

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2011, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

/**
 * @file Special Character plugin
 */



CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'specialchar',
{
    // List of available localizations.
    availableLangs : { en:1 , lat:2 , math:3},

    init : function( editor )
    {
        var pluginName = 'specialchar',
            plugin = this;
        // Register the dialog.
        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( pluginName, this.path + 'dialogs/specialchar.js' );
        editor.addCommand( pluginName,
            {
                exec : function()
                {   
                    if(CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent())
                    {
                        CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().hide();
                    }    

                    var langCode = editor.langCode;     
                    langCode = plugin.availableLangs[ langCode ] ? langCode : 'en';

                    CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(
                            CKEDITOR.getUrl( plugin.path + 'lang/' + langCode + '.js' ),
                            function()
                            {
                                CKEDITOR.tools.extend( editor.lang.specialChar, plugin.langEntries[ langCode ] );                                   
                                editor.openDialog( pluginName );                                                    
                            });
                },
                modes : { wysiwyg:1 },
                canUndo : false             
            });

        // Register the toolbar button.
        editor.ui.addButton( 'SpecialChar',
            {
                label : editor.lang.specialChar.toolbar,
                command : pluginName
            });
    }
} );

/**
  * The list of special characters visible in the Special Character dialog window.
  * @type Array
  * @example
  * config.specialChars = [ '&quot;', '&rsquo;', [ '&custom;', 'Custom label' ] ];
  * config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat( [ '&quot;', [ '&rsquo;', 'Custom label' ] ] );
  */

    CKEDITOR.config.specialChars =
        [
            '!','&quot;','#','$','%','&amp;',"'",'(',')','*','+','-','.','/',
            '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':',';',
            '&lt;','=','&gt;','?','@',
            'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
            'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
            '[',']','^','_','`',
            'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p',
            'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
            '{','|','}','~',
            "&euro;", "&lsquo;", "&rsquo;", "&ldquo;", "&rdquo;", "&ndash;", "&mdash;", "&iexcl;", "&cent;", "&pound;", "&curren;", "&yen;", "&brvbar;", "&sect;", "&uml;", "&copy;", "&ordf;", "&laquo;", "&not;", "&reg;", "&macr;", "&deg;", "&sup2;", "&sup3;", "&acute;", "&micro;", "&para;", "&middot;", "&cedil;", "&sup1;", "&ordm;", "&raquo;", "&frac14;", "&frac12;", "&frac34;", "&iquest;", "&Agrave;", "&Aacute;", "&Acirc;", "&Atilde;", "&Auml;", "&Aring;", "&AElig;", "&Ccedil;", "&Egrave;", "&Eacute;", "&Ecirc;", "&Euml;", "&Igrave;", "&Iacute;", "&Icirc;", "&Iuml;", "&ETH;", "&Ntilde;", "&Ograve;", "&Oacute;", "&Ocirc;", "&Otilde;", "&Ouml;", "&times;", "&Oslash;", "&Ugrave;", "&Uacute;", "&Ucirc;", "&Uuml;", "&Yacute;", "&THORN;", "&szlig;", "&agrave;", "&aacute;", "&acirc;", "&atilde;", "&auml;", "&aring;", "&aelig;", "&ccedil;", "&egrave;", "&eacute;", "&ecirc;", "&euml;", "&igrave;", "&iacute;", "&icirc;", "&iuml;", "&eth;", "&ntilde;", "&ograve;", "&oacute;", "&ocirc;", "&otilde;", "&ouml;", "&divide;", "&oslash;", "&ugrave;", "&uacute;", "&ucirc;", "&uuml;", "&yacute;", "&thorn;", "&yuml;", "&OElig;", "&oelig;", "&#372;", "&#374", "&#373", "&#375;", "&sbquo;", "&#8219;", "&bdquo;", "&hellip;", "&trade;", "&#9658;", "&bull;", "&rarr;", "&rArr;", "&hArr;", "&diams;", "&asymp;"
        ];


    var latin = ['ƀ','Ɓ','Ƃ','ƃ','Ƅ','ƅ','Ɔ','Ƈ','ƈ','Ɖ','Ɗ','Ƌ','ƌ','ƍ','Ǝ','Ə','Ɛ','Ƒ','ƒ','Ɠ','Ɣ','ƕ','Ɩ','Ɨ','Ƙ','ƙ','ƚ','ƛ','Ɯ','Ɲ','ƞ','Ɵ','Ơ','ơ','Ƣ','ƣ','Ƥ','ƥ','Ʀ','Ƨ','ƨ','Ʃ','ƪ','ƫ','Ƭ','ƭ','Ʈ','Ư','ư','Ʊ','Ʋ','Ƴ','ƴ','Ƶ','ƶ','Ʒ','Ƹ','ƹ','ƺ','ƻ','Ƽ','ƽ','ƾ','ƿ','ǀ','ǁ','ǂ','ǃ','Ǆ','ǅ','ǆ','Ǉ','ǈ','ǉ','Ǌ','ǋ','ǌ','Ǎ','ǎ','Ǐ','ǐ','Ǒ','ǒ','Ǔ','ǔ','Ǖ','ǖ','Ǘ','ǘ','Ǚ','ǚ','Ǜ','ǜ','ǝ','Ǟ','ǟ','Ǡ','ǡ','Ǣ','ǣ','Ǥ','ǥ','Ǧ','ǧ','Ǩ','ǩ','Ǫ','ǫ','Ǭ','ǭ','Ǯ','ǯ','ǰ','Ǳ','ǲ','ǳ','Ǵ','ǵ','Ƕ','Ƿ','Ǹ','ǹ','Ǻ','ǻ','Ǽ','ǽ','Ǿ','ǿ','Ȁ','ȁ','Ȃ','ȃ','Ȅ','ȅ','Ȇ','ȇ','Ȉ','ȉ','Ȋ','ȋ','Ȍ','ȍ','Ȏ','ȏ','Ȑ','ȑ','Ȓ','ȓ','Ȕ','ȕ','Ȗ','ȗ','Ș','ș','Ț','ț','Ȝ','ȝ','Ȟ','ȟ','Ƞ','','Ȣ','ȣ','Ȥ','ȥ','Ȧ','ȧ','Ȩ','ȩ','Ȫ','ȫ','Ȭ','ȭ','Ȯ','ȯ','Ȱ','ȱ','Ȳ','ȳ','ȷ','ȸ','ȹ','Ⱥ','Ȼ','ȼ','Ƚ','Ⱦ','ȿ','ɀ','Ɂ','ɂ','Ƀ','Ʉ','Ʌ','Ɇ','ɇ','Ɉ','ɉ','Ɋ','ɋ','Ɍ','ɍ','Ɏ','ɏ'];

    var math_operator = ['∀','∁','∂','∃','∄','∅','Δ','∇','∈','∉','ε','∋','∌','∍','∎','Π','∐','Σ','−','∓','∔','∕','','∗','∘','∙','√','∛','∜','∝','∞','∟','∠','∡','∢','∣','∤','∥','∦','∧','∨','∩','∪','∫','∬','∭','∮','∯','∰','∱','∲','∳','∴','∵','∶','∷','∸','∹','∺','∻','∼','∽','∾','∿','≀','≁','≂','≃','≄','≅','≆','≇','≈','≉','≊','≋','≌','≍','≎','≏','≐','≑','≒','≓','≔','≕','≖','≗','≘','≙','≚','≛','≜','≝','≞','≟','≠','≡','≢','≣','≤','≥','≦','≧','≨','≩','≪','≫','≬','≭','≮','≯','≰','≱','≲','≳','≴','≵','≶','≷','','','≺','≻','≼','≽','≾','≿','⊀','⊁','⊂','⊃','⊄','⊅','⊆','⊇','⊈','⊉','⊊','⊋','⊌','⊍','⊎','⊏','⊐','⊑','⊓','⊔','⊕','⊖','⊗','⊘','⊙','⊚','⊛','⊜','⊝','⊞','⊟','⊠','⊡','⊢','⊣','⊤','⊥','⊦','⊧','⊨','⊩','⊪','⊫','⊬','⊭','⊮','⊯','⊰','⊱','⊲','⊳','⊴','⊵','','','','⊹','⊺','⊻','⊼','⊽','⊿','⋀','⋁','⋂','⋃','⋄','⋅','⋆','⋇','','','⋍','⋎','⋏','⋐','⋑','⋒','⋓','⋔','⋕','⋖','⋗','⋘','⋙','⋚','⋛','⋜','⋝','⋞','⋟','⋠','⋡','⋢','⋣','⋤','⋥','⋦','⋧','⋨','⋩','⋪','⋫','⋬','⋭','⋮','⋯','⋰','⋱',];
```